# Mysql insert multiple where only a single field varies

Tags: mysql

If i have to insert several hundred rows into a table, but the data i am inserting only varies for a single column, what is the best way to do this without having several hundred separate inserts.

I.e.

```
name, lastname, lastlogin
bill  smith     2015-08-01
bill  smith     2015-08-02
bill  smith     2015-08-03
bill  smith     2015-08-04
```

Answer (score 0):

Several hundred rows? That's nothing. Just expand it and make an `INSERT` statement that has multiple values:

```
INSERT INTO the_table (name, lastname, lastlogin)
  VALUES ('bill','smith', '2015-08-01'),
     ('bill','smith', '2015-08-02'),
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables and functions in order to about writing hundred times the query:

```
    SET @variable_field=NOW();
    INSERT INTO login VALUES("bill", "smith", @variable_field);
```